# How to reset all values to initial state in vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

In vue2, we can use `Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data())` to reset all values

But how can we do the same thing (one line coding) in vue3, assuming my setup() is ....

```
setup(props, context) {
  let a = ref('value1')
  let b = ref('value2')
  let c = ref('value3')
  
  function reset() {
    Object.assign(????, ????) or ???? <-- ????
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data())` is a workaround that relies on options API internals.

It's a good practice to have reusable function for scenarios where initial state needs to be accessed more than once:

```
const getInitialData = () => ({ a: 1, ... });
```

It can be called both in `data` and `setup`.

Component state or its part can be expressed as single object. In this case it's handled the same way as Vue 2 state:

```
const formData = reactive(getInitialData());
...
Object.assign(formData, getInitialData());
```

Otherwise `a.value`, etc need to be assigned with respective initial values, either manually or with helper function:

```
let data = getInitialData();
for (let [key, ref] of Object.entries({ a, b, ... }))  
  ref.value = data[key];
```